# What are the solutions of this differential operator?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, wave-equation, transport-equation

I am thinking about the ‘complex’ transport equation:
$$\partial_t + a\cdot \nabla = 0$$
where $a \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and its elements are either real or pure imaginary. The simplest example for this operator is $n=1$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$, which is then simply the 1D transport equation:
$$\partial_t + a \partial_x = 0.$$
The simplest, more general operator in $n$ dimensions would have $a = (x_1, ..., x_n)$ where $x_i \in \{\pm1,\pm i\}$. For example, in 3D we might have:
$$\partial_t + (1, -i, -1) \cdot\nabla = 0.$$

I have not been able to find general treatments of such operators in my search, only vague references that are not so helpful, for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188983/complex-transport-equation). What are these operators called, and where can I find the general theory of them?

Comment: These are linear differential operators with constant coefficients, and can be solved using Fourier transform.